# Catel and inheritance from base class

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ioc-container, catel

I've got 2 different viewmodel which inherits from a base one. there're some services that are resolved currently in the base controller via

```
ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<xxx>
```

I know its not the best approach since it breaks the DI. I've also read that its an anti-pattern to have more than one constructor. How should I threat that scenario? Since most of the code is the same for both the viewmodels

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you inject these services in a constructors? Like this:

```
public class BaseVM
{
    protected readonly IService1 _service1;
    public BaseVM(IService1 service1)
    {
       _service1 = service1
    }
}

public class InheritedVM1: BaseVM
{
    public InheritedVM1(IService1 service1, ...other args...): base(service1
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class InheritedVM2: BaseVM
{
    public InheritedVM2(IService1 service1, ...other args...): base(service1
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

IoC will inject your services through constructors of InheritedVM, and after calling base with the injected services you can use them using _service1 field.

Comment: I tought on this... but does it respect DI pattern?

Comment: Hm, I don't see why not. As Wikipedia says "An injection is the passing of a dependency to a dependent object (a client) that would use it". Here, a client is one of your InheritedVM and a dependency is IService1. If your BaseVM is not used in any View, you can even make it abstract. I use it with Catel all the time, and I never need ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType

Comment: tell me that you also use Telerik and I marry you

Comment: I'm not. But, I appreciate the sentiment, although I'm not looking to be married :)